# In Google Analytics, is there a way to see which days have the most transactions?

Tags: google-analytics, report

I have been asked to report on which days of the week have the most orders.  I can simply do this manually by taking the date range and adding up each individual days' totals.

My questions is if there is a way to generate this report within Google Analytics without the manual steps. Maybe with some sort of distribution or bar graph?

For example:

```
Monday   : 200 transactions
Tuesday  : 180 transactions
Wednesday: 173 transactions

...etc...
```

Does a report like that exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to "Customization" -> New Custom Report -> Dimension "Day of week" (or Date) -> metric "Transactions" -> (optional: add filters at you liking) -> save.